# Transforming Map field in avro schema to string using kafka SMT in jdbc-sink-connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have an avro schema defined as follows:

```
[    
{
    "namespace": "com.fun.message",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "FileData",
    "doc": "Avro Schema for FileData",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "id", "type": "string", "doc": "Unique file id" },
        {"name": "absolutePath", "type": "string", "doc": "Absolute path of file" },
        {"name": "fileName", "type": "string", "doc": "File name" },
        {"name": "source", "type": "string", "doc": "unique identification of source" },
        {"name": "metaData", "type": {"type": "map", "values": "string"}}
    ]
}
]
```

I want to push this data to postgres using jdbc-sink-connector so that I can transform the `"metaData"` field (which is map type) in my schema to a string. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you researched the Simple message transforms?

Comment: Yes i did lot of research on SMT and went through that documentations. @cricket_007

Comment: Okay, and what issues are you having implementing your own? Alternatively, have you tried just running a KStreams `mapValues()` function over the data before the JDBC sink is applied?

Comment: Yes i deployed a kafka stream processor which does this transformation for me.@cricket_007

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SMTs and AFAIK there is currently no SMT that perfectly meets your requirement (`ExtractField` is a `Map.get` operation and therefore nested fields cannot be extracted in one pass). You could take a look at Debezium's [`io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope`](https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/master/debezium-core/src/main/java/io/debezium/transforms/UnwrapFromEnvelope.java) SMT which you can modify in order to extract nested fields.

`UnwrapFromEnvelope` is being used for [CDC Event Flattening](https://debezium.io/docs/configuration/event-flattening/) in order to extract fields from more complex structures like the data formed by Debezium (which I believe is similar to your structure).

Comment: Yes i found that. But this does flattening a struct or map. So if i want to convert that Map or Struct to String then i need to customize this transformation?